# How to import all the photos from a file into Blender?

Tags: python, image, import, blender

I want to import all the photos from a file into Blender. Once imported I'm changing the material and moving it into a unique position before moving on to the next photo.

As it stand it runs but only produces the same photo. How can I make the file name count upward while skipping gaps in the counting sequence to make up for missing file names.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0))
my_variable = 0
location = (my_variable * 5) * 2
num_photo = 1669 + my_variable
#file_name = "DSA_1669.JPG"
while my_variable < 64:
    bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane(files=[{"name":"DSA_1669.JPG", "name":"DSA_1669.JPG"}], directory="E:\\Pictures\\Cannabis\\Dream Catcher Nug\\JPG\\", relative=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-1.5708, orient_axis='Y', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.data.materials["DSA_1669"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[4].default_value = 0.95614
    bpy.data.materials["DSA_1669"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[7].default_value = 0.0789474
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, location, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    my_variable += 1
```

Comment: Where are you stuck, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Check if a file exists in Python: https://www.guru99.com/python-check-if-file-exists.html

Format a string in Python: https://dzone.com/articles/python-string-format-examples

```
import os.path
from os import path

num_photo = 1669
total_photos = 64
photo_path = "C:\\Pictures\\JPG\\"  # replace with the actual folder
for photo_num in range(total_photos):
    image_name = f"DSA{num_photo + photo_num}"
    file_name = image_name + "JPG"
    if not path.exists(photo_path + file_name):
        continue  # file didn't exist, skip over it
```

In this case, `image_name` would be like `"DSA_1669"` and `file_name` would be like `"DSA_1669.JPG"`.